# Getting "Operation could destabilize the runtime." Exception for hand-constructed LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq

In my program I make my LINQ expression from hand (I'm translating my own expression tree into LINQ - we currently use EF but that may change so I'm future-proofing this part of the app by using my own expressions and writing something that converts it into the LINQ and executes it.).

I'm getting a "Operation could destabilize the runtime" exception.

I'm currently implementing aggregates, so I suspect it's this right here in the expression tree.  If this isn't the cause, then any ideas on how to figure out what's causing the issue?

```
.Lambda #Lambda7<System.Func`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel,Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel],Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel]>(System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel,Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel] $jg)
{
    .New Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel(){
        Left = .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(
            $jg,
            .Lambda #Lambda8<System.Func`2[Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel,System.Decimal]>),
        Right = .New Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel(){
            Left = (System.Object)((Mock.Sandbox.PartyDataObject)((.Call System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault($jg)).Right).Left).PartyID
        }
    }
}

.Lambda #Lambda8<System.Func`2[Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel,System.Decimal]>(Plugins.LinqToStar.JoinedModel $aggregateJ)
{
    (System.Decimal)((System.Object)((Mock.Sandbox.AccountDataObject)$aggregateJ.Left).Current0)
}
```

Comment: [*we currently use EF but that may change so I'm future-proofing this part of the app by using my own expressions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering)

Comment: Any chance we can see the code that is building and/or executing the expression trees? in particular, that message suggests that it is using LINQ-to-Objects (and thus compiling the expression-tree to a delegate) - in which case this *isn't correctly using EF anyway*

Comment: I'm using LINQ-to-objects to see if it's doable there, first, as that will be hard enough.  Then I figure I'd massage it into LINQ that EF can execute.  The code is pretty lengthy and is split up over multiple files.  Anything in particular you want to see?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared well, re-read the question from my perspective (assume I'm someone with a chance of being able to answer it, i.e. someone who understands LINQ, expression-trees, and dynamic meta-programming etc); "my code doesn't work; there is a lot of code; and I can't show it to you" - I'm not sure there's much I can do from there. Your best bet would be to simplify it down to a *reproducible example*. You might well find that in doing so *you find the problem*.

Comment: *"currently use EF but that may change"* So encapsulate your EF context into a data access object that exposes `IQueryable` collections, use LINQ, and if it changes in future, swap out the data access object. This is what Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection are for. LINQ doesn't have to be used with EF; hiding your EF-specific bits (ie. your `DbContext`) behind an interface and setting up an IoC container to provide it as needed is **MUCH** easier than manually converting expression trees to valid LINQ like you're attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing an explicit cast from a `decimal` (the result of the aggregate) to an `object` in my Expression tree.